# Swift - Generic Structs in array, casting back and sending as a method parameter

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

I am having a generic struct that can be passed to a generic method as a parameter. This works well.

But I need to store these structs in an array and pass it to that generic method later.
The problem is that I cannot cast it back to the type.

Playground code will explain what is my problem:

```swift
import Foundation

protocol ThingProtocol { }

struct Thing<T>: ThingProtocol {
}

func doSomethingWithThing<T>(thing: Thing<T>) {
    print(thing)
}

let t1 = Thing<Int>()
let t2 = Thing<String>()
let t3 = Thing<Date> ()

doSomethingWithThing(thing: t1)
doSomethingWithThing(thing: t2)
doSomethingWithThing(thing: t3)

var thingArray = [t1, t2, t3] as [ThingProtocol]

thingArray.forEach {
    //How to call doSomethingWithThing with $0?
    //doSomethingWithThing(thing: $0)
}
```

I've been trying to use protocols, but that didn't work well.
All Generics conform to Decodable protocol, but I cannot make a use of it.

Any ideas of how to achieve something like that?

PS. method doSomethingWithThing cannot be changed to use a protocol, it needs to be a generic method
I cannot extend all used types in that generic (too many of them)

Comment: This question is probably too abstract to answer, since you've added so many restrictions on the solution. What you're asking for, in the way you're asking for it, is impossible. `doSomethingWithThing<Int>` and `doSomethingWithThing<String>` are completely different functions, created at compile time (just like `doSomethingWithInt` and `doSomethingWithString` are completely different functions). If what you're asking for were possible, the runtime would have to be able to compile a new function. You'll need to present this problem in a more concrete form so we can help find the real problem.

Comment: In terms of "more concrete," in particular you need to explain why "method doSomethingWithThing cannot be changed to use a protocol." That would trivially resolve your problem as you've presented it, so understanding this restriction is key to solving the whole thing. Most importantly, what does `doSomethingWithThing` actually do with its `T` parameter?